# all links is not working except home url in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have successfully run a Laravel project in Xampp. But only home url is working perfectly. But for all other links(ex : menu, item details etc) css and js is not working.

my home url is

> http://localhost:90/office/sencare/

and sample css or js links are

> http://localhost:90/office/sencare/frontend/css/style.css

But for all others links this css or js links will change automatically ex :

> http://localhost:90/frontend/css/style.css

`office/sencare` is missing after `localhost:90`.

**.env file**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Dm34MLg8AbQk4ADyIG9cYPaIwYbQgrUgrN7Ani/x+JA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:90/office/sencare/
```

**.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**sample.blade.php**
[image]

Can't find the solution where to change.

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance.

Please tell me if anything else needed

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the theme.blade.php

Comment: @khaleelibrahim...I have updated my post with screenshot

Comment: you should review Laravel docs , it seems you are a newbie and don't know any thing about Files Structures and routes in Laravel

Comment: @Netlog.....Do you find any problem in my post? if yes then suggest me please if you are experienced in Laravel.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: This is a really common issue with Laravel, at least in versions 6 & above. I had mitigated it somehow ( I don't remember how). Then, following along in Laracasts from Scratch for Laravel 6, we created a link for "articles" that involved a subfolder under 'views'. That's ALL I did, and with that all of my navigation now routes to the public/index.php (or webroot). The laravel people don't care about XAMPP - they want you to use their jumble of junk that apparently works ok locally. But I've seen when it's uploaded to a regular VPS, it doesn't always work as well.

Comment: @Netlog, Laravel docs don't show any info on why a path may not work in an XAMPP env. And the laracasts hosts don't answer questions about it. Not that I've seen. On the other hand, Yii works right out of the box with the .htaccess file that's installed with it. I've never had any issues with Yii on XAMPP or Apache in general.

Answer (score 0):

> rootfolder/public/frontend/css/style.css

this should be the path to style.css as per your code
verify it